# ¿Por qué se detiene cronómetro al ejecutarse el prompt de beforeunload con ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Devs, tengo un cronómetro que se paraliza cuando se ejecuta `beforeunload` al intentar cambiar de dirección o actualizar la página. Cuando se cancela el prompt el cronómetro continua. Pero ese no es el comportamiento que espero.

Espero que aunque aparezca el prompt de `beforeunload` el cronómetro siga contando...

El cronómetro funciona con useEffect y useRef, normal.

Y aquí está mi uso de `beforeunload`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => event.preventDefault();
    if (checkTestState(TEST_STATES.IN_PROCESS)) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    }
    return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pretendes es **imposible**.

Tal y como funciona Javascript, los eventos de `setTimeout( )` o `setInterval( )` dependen de que [el bucle de eventos del lenguaje](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) esté en ejecución. Dependen de que solo se realicen tareas **asíncronas**.

Cualquier tarea **síncrona** (*prompt*, operaciones AJAX síncronas, ...) detiene el bucle de eventos, con lo que cualquier `setTimeout( )` o `setInterval( )` **deja de ejecutarse** hasta que se reanude el ciclo de eventos.

Una alternativa es usar [`Date.now( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/now) para controlar el tiempo real, se esté o no en el bucle de eventos:

```js
const BeginShutdown = Date.now( );
var iHandler = setInterval( function( ) {
  var millis = Date.now( ) - BeginShutdown;

  if( millis > 5000 ) {
    window.clearInterval( iHandler );
    window.alert( `Han pasado ${millis} milisegundos.` );
  }
}, 250 );

window.confirm( "Este mensaje BLOQUEA el bucle de eventos." );
```

El código anterior muestra un mensaje. Si se pulsa en <kbd>aceptar</kbd>:

- **Antes** de que pasen 5 segundos, el `alert( )` se muestra en el momento establecido, 5 segundos después de comenzar la ejecución.
- **Después** de que pasen 5 segundos, el `alert( )` se muestra en cuanto se abandone el `message( )`.

Comment: Gracias, esto me da una idea de como manejarlo.